# Get status transaction Payment

Tags: payment-gateway, cybersource

I am trying to retrieve the status of a payment transaction through the sdk "" using the "refreshPaymentStatus" method of the "PaymentsApi" class but I get an error

--- Invokers.ApiClient : {"submitTimeUtc":"2023-08-28T22:47:13Z","status":"404","errorInformation":{"reason":"NOT_FOUND ","message":"The requested resource does not exist."}}
---  Invokers.ApiClient : ApiException : 404 Not Found

I am passing the Id retrieved from the PtsV2PaymentsPost201Response when I create the payment and I am also sending the code and ReconciliationId... how can I check the status of a transaction to know if it was paid or declined

I use sdk version: cybersource-rest-client-java:0.0.55

Note: I am also using the "Api reference" in the "Check a Payment Status" method and I get the same error.

https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#payments_payments_check-a-payment-status

I have tried the API reference in the payments_payments_check-a-payment-status method but I also get a 404 error
https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#payments_payments_check-a-payment-status

How can I check the status of a transaction after making an authorization or capture

Answer (score 1):

Are you using one of the alternate payment e.g. KCP? The Check a Payment Status API is used for Alternate Payments.

If you are not doing alternate payments, use the Transaction Detail API instead:
https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#transaction-details_transaction-details_retrieve-a-transaction